# What does it mean for a field to be of order n?

Tags: field-theory

I understand what a field is. But I do not understand what it means for a field to be of order n. Can someone explain please?

Comment: It means it has $n$ elements.

Comment: You may be interested in this fact: it is true that if a field has $m$ elements than $m$ is of the form $p^{n}$ where $p$ is some prime. For example there is no field with $6$ elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the field has exactly $n$ elements.